# Session replication is not working as expected in Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform - Version 6.3.0.GA

Tags: jboss

I'm bit new to JBoss, could you please help me out in finding the root cause in the below mentioned issue.Thanks and much appreciated,

> Issue: Session replication is not happening between master(domain
>   controller) and slave(host). Following are the logs,

From master:

```
[Server:server-three] 07:53:38,246 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) ISPN000078: Starting JGroups Channel
[Server:server-three] 07:53:38,260 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65)
[Server:server-three] 07:53:38,260 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) -------------------------------------------------------------------
[Server:server-three] 07:53:38,261 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) GMS: address=master:server-three/web, cluster=web, physical address=10.78.216.145:7850
[Server:server-three] 07:53:38,261 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) -------------------------------------------------------------------
[Host Controller] 07:53:40,511 INFO  [org.jboss.as.domain] (Host Controller Service Threads - 25) JBAS010918: Registered remote slave host "slave", JBoss EAP 6.3.0.GA (AS 7.4.0.Final-redhat-19)
[Server:server-three] 07:53:41,273 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view: [master:server-three/web|0] [master:server-three/web]
[Server:server-three] 07:53:41,275 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) ISPN000079: Cache local address is master:server-three/web, physical addresses are [10.78.216.145:7850]
[Server:server-three] 07:53:41,279 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Delirium' 5.2.10.Final
[Server:server-three] 07:53:41,288 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS010238: Number of cluster members: 1
```

From slave:

```
[Server:server-three-slave] 07:53:36,274 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) ISPN000078: Starting JGroups Channel
[Server:server-three-slave] 07:53:36,287 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67)
[Server:server-three-slave] 07:53:36,287 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) -------------------------------------------------------------------
[Server:server-three-slave] 07:53:36,288 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) GMS: address=slave:server-three-slave/web, cluster=web, physical address=10.78.216.36:7850
[Server:server-three-slave] 07:53:36,288 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) -------------------------------------------------------------------
[Server:server-three-slave] 07:53:39,301 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view: [slave:server-three-slave/web|0] [slave:server-three-slave/web]
[Server:server-three-slave] 07:53:39,302 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) ISPN000079: Cache local address is slave:server-three-slave/web, physical addresses are [10.78.216.36:7850]
[Server:server-three-slave] 07:53:39,306 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Delirium' 5.2.10.Final
[Server:server-three-slave] 07:53:39,315 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010238: Number of cluster members: 1
```

I'm advertising my cluster and i can see the both master and slave nodes are present in the UI,
`https://10.78.X.X:8445/mod_cluster_manager`,

I have disabled firewall and SELinux to avoid network problems.I believe, i have made all the required configurations in `domain.xml` and `ssl.conf` of httpd. I have also added  `<distributable/>` tag and `jboss-web.xml` changes in my war. It'd be of more help if anyone of you direct me in a different direction as i'm totally lost,

Even i can see the following in my master log:

```
[Host Controller] 07:18:58,862 INFO  [org.jboss.as.domain] (Host Controller Service Threads - 28) JBAS010918: Registered remote slave host "slave", JBoss EAP 6.3.0.GA (AS 7.4.0.Final-redhat-19)
[Server:server-three] 07:18:59,029 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view: [master:server-three/web|0] [master:server-three/web]
```

I have tried adding ProxyPass with stickySession, didn't get much luck. any suggestion or help will be much appreciated,

Thanks,
Joy.

Answer (score 1):

The `<distributable/>` tag  must be added to the `web.xml` file not in `jboss-web.xml`

> **Enable Session Replication in Your Application**
>
> **Overview**
>   To take advantage of the JBoss Enterprise Application Platform's High Availability (HA) > features, configure your application
>   to be distributable. This procedure shows how to do that, and then
>   explains some of the advanced configuration options you can use.
>
> 1. **Required:** Indicate that your application is distributable.
>
> If your application is not marked as distributable, its sessions will
>   never be distributed. Add the `<distributable />` element inside the
>   `<web-app>` tag of your application's `web.xml` discriptor file. Here
>   is an example.
>
> ```
> <web-app  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
>           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
>           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
>                               http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" 
>           version="2.4">
>
>       <distributable/>
>
> </web-app>
> ```

See more: [Chapter 7. Clustering in Web Applications](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/chap-Clustering_in_Web_Applications.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I actually mentioned as 'and' not 'in' ," I have also added  <distributable/> tag and jboss-web.xml changes in my war". I added ,disturbutable tag in web.xml only ,Apreciate.